# Magento - Add filter to getLoadedProductCollection()

Tags: magento, collections, product

In my magento store (ce-1.9.0) I have setup a custom product attribute:

```
custom_depth_check
```

And the attribute has the setting of

```
Used in Product Listing : Yes
Used for Sorting in Product Listing : Yes
```

I now need to filter any `getLoadedProductCollection()` with this attribute. The attribute will either be set at:

```
null
0
1
```

I need to filter all instances of `getLoadedProductCollection()` so that it will EXLCUDE any products with

```
custom_depth_check : 1
```

I have tried to clear and reload like so:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()
->clear()
->addAttributeToFilter('custom_depth_check', array('neq' => 1));
```

But that results in an empty collection. I also tried adding `->load()` at the end but again nothing comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection is loaded in the file:
app/code/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php
in the function:
_getProductCollection()

Do a local ovveride by copyng that file in local folder
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

and add your new filters just before the line

```
$this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());
```

your code will be like:

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_depth_check', array('neq' => 1)); //Your new filter
$this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());
```

best regards
Giuseppe

Comment: I've just tried the above and it results in an empty collection. I've cleared all my caches after making the change

Comment: try to change the filter condition in example 'eq' => "1" and be sure to have the 'custom_depth_check'  added to the selected attribute if not use the addAttributeToSelect('custom_depth_check') instruction

Comment: For some reason this worked when i used `->addAttributeToFilter('custom_depth_check', '0'))` but `eq` `neq` and `null` didn't. I have had to set all other products at 0 and use the above snippet to get this working

Comment: I've suspected that the problem may be related to the filter, happy to know that you solve. Please accept my answer if you feel appropriate to do it.